# How to use mysql sessions to store and reuse data from specific query for additional queries?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm teaching myself how to use mysql and php to create a simple interactive we site. This will be for internal use only and I'm not too concerned with security. Currently my database consists of two tables, teacher_user and student_user.

Teacher users log in and I compare what they complete in the online form with what is stored in the database. If they match in the database, the teacher can continue into the web site. The meat of the php code is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM teacher_user WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("username");
session_register("password");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Then on each html page I have:

```
<?
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

My question is related to what the teacher user and their initial log in with their username and password. I would like to store their username across all pages in the web site and be able to recall their username for queries on the student_user table. The student_user table and teacher_user table both contain the teacher's username.

I would like to query the student_user table by the teacher's username so that I can produce a query result of just those students in a particular teacher's classroom.

I have attempted multiple times at saving the teacher's $username into a `".$_session['username']` session can't seem to make it echo out the teacher's username on any subsequent page as a test.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if so, does anyone have a simple example that they could share?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, the `session_register` function is now deprecated, simply use the session variables as you please, something like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Once the username and password have been validated, this way in every page you use `session_start()` your variables will be there.

Edit:

To be specific, the

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

goes inside the

```
if($count==1){
```

condition.